# Speed Up Hardware Post by Disabling Features

Tags: motherboard, performance-tuning

In my Mobo settings I have the following

> OnChip IDE Channel10 [Enabled]
>   Primary Master PIO [Auto]
>   Primary Slave PIO [Auto]
>   Primary Master UDMA [Auto]
>   Primary Slave UDMA [Auto]
>   IDE DMA transfer access [Enabled]
>   Serial-ATA Controller [Enabled]
>   IDE Prefetch Mode [Enabled]

Now I'm not using any IDE devices (only a SATA SSD, a SATA HDD, and a SATA DVDRom)

Is it ok to disable a bunch of these IDE features? If so, which ones would you disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SATA *is* "[IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#IDE_and_ATA-1)", well sort of. ;)

You're not using and PATA devices, so it's hard to tell if they mean 'PATA' by IDE.

So without knowing you motherboard's specifics, and a little experience with the BIOS setup in question, those options are a little vague.  Any of them could and, probably would, affect your SATA drives.

You're better bet may be to set them to match the drives' specs so that you don't have to wait for the Auto-detect.

But really, the boot time you will save by disabling these options will probably be negligible in today's BIOS', and IMO it's more of a pain to maintain over time than it's worth, so Auto is your friend. :)

Comment: alright, thanks. It just sucks that I have an SSD running XBMC Live, and the MOBO post takes twice as long and the OS boot.